# asp.net c# dropdown list findbytext keeps adding item?

Tags: c#, asp.net

May be a noob question. But I am scratching my head what I am doing wrong here.

```
    protected void ddlClientNum_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Bussiness.GetConnectionString("Default")))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct client_name from [dbo].[customer_master] where client_number=" + ddlClientNum.SelectedItem.Text + " order by client_name", con);
                            adapter.Fill(dt);
                            ddlClientName.DataSource = dt;
                            ddlClientName.DataTextField = "client_name";
                            ddlClientName.DataValueField = "client_name";
                            ddlClientName.DataBind();
                            ddlClientName.ClearSelection();
                            //ddlClientName.SelectedValue = ddlClientName.Items.FindByText((ddlClientNum.SelectedItem.Text).ToString()).Value;
                             //ddlClientName.SelectedValue = ddlClientName.Items.FindByText((dt.Rows[0][0]).ToString()).Value;
                            //ddlClientName.Items.FindByText((dt.Rows[0][0]).ToString()).Selected = true;
                            ddlClientName.SelectedIndex = ddlClientName.Items.IndexOf(ddlClientName.Items.FindByText((dt.Rows[0][0]).ToString()));
                 }
           }
   }
```

I am populating client number and client name dropdownlist on page load. On selection of client number I need to select the respective client name but I don't want to Clear the Items. I need users to be able to see the other client names but need to Select the Client name for selected client Number. I Have tried the 3 things but it keeps adding the selected client name.

So, selected client name is occurring as many times I select the respective Client Number and stays there even if I select another client Number.

e.g. I select Client Number :176  | Client Name shows "XYZ Client" selected but occurs twice in the list. If I select any other client number and then again select 176 I can see "XYZ Client" occuring in the list thrice.

Blues and yellows are the repeating ones.
[image]

Comment: Are the clientNumber and ClientName coming from the same table or from different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you don't need to bind again here. just set the selected index.

Also, I suggest you to use Parameterized queries. Otherwise, It will be vulnerable to SQL injection.
For more info : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/

```
  protected void ddlClientNum_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Bussiness.GetConnectionString("Default")))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct client_name from [dbo].[customer_master] where client_number=" + ddlClientNum.SelectedItem.Text + " order by client_name", con);
                            adapter.Fill(dt);
                            ddlClientName.ClearSelection();
                            ddlClientName.SelectedIndex = ddlClientName.Items.IndexOf(ddlClientName.Items.FindByText((dt.Rows[0][0]).ToString()));
                 }
           }
   }
```

Comment: No, that will clear all the items. That I don't want. I want all the items there but the selected item should be the one related to Selected Client Number.

Comment: @Sak Updated. check it.

Comment: Nope, it still adds up multiple values.

Comment: Databind() was the evil.

Comment: Yes. That's what i try to convey you.